# preserve the width of div element with background image

Tags: css, background, sprite

I have `<div>` element with background image from sprite. On left and right of that `<div>` I have `<input>` buttons (prev, next).
The thing is that `<div>` with background doesn't seem to have any width, so it is squeezed between (and covered with) the two buttons.

The question is: how do I preserve the width of the `<div>` element?

The example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/meridius/4Dk2n/

**EDIT:**

I won't mind restructuring the elements!

Comment: in this case you could just add a padding-right: 50px; to .sprite-BKing. but <div>'s usually need at least a &nbsp; to have width applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I added one `<div>` wrap for buttons and figure and alter the css and here is the working result.

http://jsfiddle.net/meridius/4Dk2n/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `min-width` property of the `<div>`.

```
.sprites-sachy { 
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: While your suggestion sort of works (the image is still covered under the buttons), I'd like to avoid setting specific width. Is there anything else I could do?

Answer (score 0):

```
min-width:100px
```

or

```
padding-right:50px
```

or

or put a `&nbsp;` into the div element (so it's not empty) and add a `width:100px;`